# update-initramfs is disabled (live system is running without media mounted on /run/live/medium)

Tags: kali-linux, nvidia, initramfs

I'm trying to install nvidia drivers by following steps in [this](https://github.com/europa502/Installing-Nvidia-drivers-on-Kali-Linux) site. But I'm unbale to update `initramfs`
as the title says, its showing:

> I: update-initramfs is disabled (live system is running without media mounted on /run/live/medium).

Comment: Apparently you are using a *live* system. Those guides are for *installed* OS.

Comment: so i cant update initramfs for a live system? i do have persistance enabled

Answer (score 1):

Run this

```
/usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools
```

> On a live system, `update-initramfs` is replaced with `live-update-initramfs`, which is disabled when running in a live, read-only system.
>
> `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs` is a symlink to `/bin/live-update-initramfs`

Just worked for me on Kali Live 2022.3